# Character array taken from text file: index out of range

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexing, char

I'm writing a program to take an input of a text file containing a 50 by 50 block of three different characters: # , * and / , and colour each pixel of an output PNG file in accordance with each symbol so that there is a colour associated with each of the characters.

However, I am seeing the error that ***"String index is out of range: 2500" at line 43.***

I know though that this text file that is being read in has exactly 50 lines with 50 characters on each, which means a total of 2500 items, so what is the issue? Help would be much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 

public class Lab_Week8_ImgFrmTxtFINAL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {  

    int image_width = 50;
    int image_height = 50;
    String output_file_path = ("image.png");
    String input_file_path = "superimage.txt";
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int a = 255;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (new FileInputStream(input_file_path));
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0; 


    if(image_width <= 0 || image_height <= 0) {
        System.err.println("Width and Height have to be strictly positive!");
    }

    if(x < 0 || y < 0) {
        System.err.println("Coordinates (x, y) cannot be negative numbers!");
    }

    if(r < 0 || r > 255 || g < 0 || g > 255 || b < 0 || b > 255) {
        System.err.println("Colour values (r, g, b) have to be between 0 and 255!");
        }   

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage (image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    while (reader.hasNextLine()){
        char c = reader.next().charAt(i);
        for (i = 0; i < image_width * image_height; i++)
        {

        int p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        for (x = 0; x < image_width; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < image_height; y++){

                if (c == ('#'))
                {p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                image.setRGB(x, y, p);
                }

                else if (c == ('/'))
                {p = (a << 0) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
                    image.setRGB(x , y , p);
                }

                else if (c == ('*'))
                {p = (a << 8) | (r << 16) | (g << 24) | b;
                    image.setRGB(x , y , p);
                }
            }   
        x += 1;
    }
    y += 1;
    x = 0;
    }

    }
    File f = new File (output_file_path);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", f);

    reader.close();
}
}
```

Comment: the line where you set char c to index i is before the for loop that increments i. Did you mean to do that? When the for loop ends, i is 2500, which is greater than the highest index of 2499

Comment: @Tyler thanks Tyler, just me forgetting the 0-indexing again! I've now changed it to image_width * image_height - 1 and moved the setting of c to within the first for loop, However, I'm now getting the "NoSuchElement Exception" on line 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
while (reader.hasNextLine())
```

with

```
while (i < image_width * image_height && reader.hasNextLine())
```

The problem with your code is that when `i = image_width * image_height`, the `for` loop stops but the `while` loop still continues and tries to execute `char c = reader.next().charAt(i);` causing `String index is out of range: 2500`.

**Update:** based on the discussion the comment/chat, you need to change your code as follows:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {          
    for (i = 0; i < image_width * image_height ; i++) {             
        int p = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        for (x = 0; x < image_width && reader.hasNext(); x++) {
            char c = reader.next().charAt(i);
```

Comment: I'm now getting a "NoSuchElement Exception" on line 45

Comment: Lines 42 to 45: while ((i < image_width * image_height && reader.hasNextLine())){
        for (i = 0; i < image_width * image_height  - 1; i++)
        {
            char c = reader.next().charAt(i);

Comment: One of those lines is simply a { bracket on its own. Line 45 is  char c = reader.next().charAt(i);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204512/discussion-between-charlie-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).